# Update internal links migrating from Drupal to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, drupal, migration

Hi I have imported my Drupal content to WordPress and they are working fine with new URLs but many internal links are still pointing to Old Drupal nodes. is there any automatic way to update those links? I guess there is not because the new URL of the blogs are like this:

```
example.com/blog/how-to-make-website/
```

but on drupal it is like

```
example.com/nodes/218
```

how would a script detect that 218 is the article with title how to make website

is there anything that can do the job? am I missing something? I searched alot and couldnt find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about URLs , they can be fixed later by using [generate Slugs](https://www.jerrytravis.com/598/wordpress-plugin-to-generate-post-slugs) plugin.

You need to import all the data by using `$wpdb` queries first.

Go to Tools->Generate Slugs from admin panel and generate all the slugs so the WP rewrites the URL's correctly for each post.

Comment: Thank you! can you please elaborate `$wpdb` part? I imported Articles via XML I just need to fix there internal links pointing to drupal site. Will Generate Slug work with that?

Comment: Checkout this : $get_image = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT f.entity_id,f.field_product_image_fid,fl.filename,fl.uri FROM field_data_field_product_image as f LEFT JOIN file_managed as fl ON fl.fid=f.field_product_image_fid WHERE f.entity_id=".$dpr['id'],ARRAY_A);

$wpdb works when you want to copy the data from drupal database to wordpress database. If you have already copied/migrated the Data , then just use the plugin only.